# AppArmor, Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: command-line, apparmor

[image: Last command input to check status]Good day, I'm currently a newbie at Linux.
I've been doing well as I have managed to find most of the commands I have needed so far on google.I found a link on google that said to start you first need to dissable AppArmor then restart.
However I am struggling to restart the AppArmor on my system. I do have the idea that i might have made a mistake and removed it entirely.
Everything that I have found so far on google is mostly for older versions of Ubuntu (14.04)
Can anyone possibly help me with the correct command to rectify my problem and possibly even setup a profile corectly.

Regards, Roy

Comment: That's unusual. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1257916/edit) to show us what leads you to believe that AppArmor needs to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04 you can *restart* all services with a similar command, given form systemd:

```
sudo systemctl restart apparmor.service
```

---

Note that you can check how apparmor is doing, by asking for the *status* (no admin privileges needed here)

```
systemctl status apparmor.service
```

there you get some hint's. Tell us what the problem was, or edit the output into your question, so we can help you further.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, however I am not sure what exactly the problem might be. Even the commands that you gave me don't do anything at all. When I type it in the terminal it asks for a password then after that nothing happens.

Comment: the restart command does not give you an output, but the status command should give you some output

Comment: I'm still a bit new to command Line, perhaps if you could help me out with the status command then. I would be very grateful...

Comment: If you deinstalled the AppArmor, the apps should not be compromised. It woud help to know what you need.

Comment: You can give us a screenshot of the second command: `systemctl status apparmor.service`

Comment: Good Morning, well i was most unfortunate as i had to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 as my hard drive had crashed. i just tried the commands you gave me previously and this time they worked. but now my next question, how do i setup a profile?

Comment: I just took a screenshot but have no idea how to put it up here

Comment: That is an other question, so i suggest you to search, whether sombody already ask that question. If not, feel free to ask a new question. If my answer helped you, you can [vote and accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) it.